# Longer History of SQL Server Jobs

Tags: sql-server

When I check the SQL Server job it only shows for short period of time like few weeks back only

is there any way I can keep the job history for much longer period

[image]

Comment: Have you tried looking into sysjobactivity and sysjobhistory in MSDB database ?

Comment: This probably has to do with your History settings for SQL Server Agent. If you right click the agent, go to properties->history, you can modify the amount of history you keep (either by amount of rows or by date).

Comment: @ZLK Thanks. If you put this as an answer so I mark it as the right answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has to do with History settings in SQL Server Agent.

In the **History** tab of the **Properties** of your SQL Server Agent, you have the option of limiting job history size by rows (by individual job and by overall amount of rows) as well as choosing whether to delete history after a certain amount of time.